# Copy GRANTS from one ROLE to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a ROLE in PostgreSQL, called `operator`, now I created a new ROLE called `customer`.

As there are many grants that have been applied to `operator` over the years (select, execute, delete, procedures, generators, etc...), there is no old documentation of the grants he has.

Is it possible to replicate the grants currently applied in the ROLE `operator` to the `customer`?